# buffering a set of lines from a file and storing it in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, buffer

This might be a very inefficient way to do it, but its sort of working

This code reads through a file, stores 8 line of text at a time in a global array (Would like a better option to do this if possible ) and dispatches for further processing.

here's the code

```
int count = 0;             //global
char *array_buffer[8];     //global

void line(char *line_char)
{

    int lent = strlen(line_char);
    array_buffer[count] = line_char;

    printf("%d\n",count);

    if (count == 8)
    {

        int row,col;
        for(row = 0; row<count; row++){
            printf("%d\n",row);
            for(col = 0; col<=lent; col++) {
                printf("%c", array_buffer[row][col]);
            }
        printf("\n");   
        }
    count = 0;
    }

    count++;
}



int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    clock_t start = clock();

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file %s",argv[1]);
    }
    char buff[512];

    while (fgets(buff, 512, fp) != NULL )
    {
        line(buff);             /*sending out an array having one line*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that while printing out the contents of array_buffer, its printing out the last line in the buffer 8 times. (i.e. the 8th line its reading in every cycle). Its pretty obvious that

```
array_buff[0]
....
array_buff[7]
```

all point to the address of line 8

any help in solving this ? I know it might not be the correct way to buffer something at all !

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, plenty of people don't understand pointers well when they first start programming in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stale pointer, here I will explain

```
while (fgets(buff, 512, fp) != NULL )
{
    //buff updated
    line(buff);
    //...
    //inside of the line function
        somepointertopointers[currIndex]=buff;
```

now it is looking at the location at buff, so all of the elements are looking at the same location, you need to copy the chars, or make a longer buffer and make sure you are updating the location the pointer is looking at, you can make 8 separate char[] pointers as well

This will give you the result you want

```
buff[512][8];
char** curr = buff;
while(fget(*curr,512,fp)!= NULL)
{
     line(*curr);
     curr++;
}
```

or alternatively you could allocate the buffer that is passed

```
#def BUFF_SIZE 512
#def BUFF_ARRAY_LEN 8


//put this somewhere before calling line 
//to initialize your array_buffer
for(i=0;i<BUFF_ARRAY_LEN;i++)
{
    array_buffer[i]=NULL;
}

...

//update in function line
//makes more sense to just use 
//the max len of a line
if(array_buffer[count] == NULL)
    array_buffer[count]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFF_SIZE);
strcpy(array_buffer[count],line_char);

...

//you will also need to
//clean up after you are 
//done with the memory
for(i=0;i<BUFF_ARRAY_LEN;i++)
{
    free(array_buffer[i]);
}
```

Comment: hmm but what i have is somepointer[count] = buff, and count updates on each iteration of line().

Comment: I know I changed up the example to match yours, it really doesn't matter the principle is the same, all of your pointer pointers are pointing to the same pointer. You need to either allocate more memory or change the length of the buffer

Comment: thanks, i got it sorted out, I was anyway thinking of using malloc later on, so its best i get started on it straight away !

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach that leads to the behavior that you see is that your code never copies the data from the buffer. This line

```
array_buffer[count] = line_char;
```

puts a pointer to the same `char buff[512]` from `main` at all eight locations. Subsequent calls to `fgets` override the content of previous reads, so you end up with eight copies of the last line.

You can fix this issue by making a copy, e.g. with `strdup` or by allocating memory with `malloc` and making a copy. You need to `free` everything that you allocate, though.

Comment: exactly what i thought, but then wont count take care of that ? count is updating after every iteration of line() so it should change ?

Comment: @Sid5427 No, incrementing `count` simply puts the same pointer to a different array element, but the memory for the string itself remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
void line(char *line_char){
    if (count == 8){
        int row,col;
        for(row = 0; row<count; row++){
            printf("%2d:",row);
            printf("%s", array_buffer[row]);
            free(array_buffer[row]);
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    int lent = strlen(line_char);
    array_buffer[count] = malloc((lent + 1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(array_buffer[count], line_char);
    //printf("%d\n", count);
    count++;
}
```